# Can I camp on a campsite under 18 in Italy?

Tags: camping, hostels

I just realised you can't sleep in hostels if you're under 18 years old. Is this the same for staying at a campsite in Italy? I really need help because I already planned a whole vacation around camping.

Comment: Someone else may be better placed to give a proper answer. But many hostels do allow you to stay alone of under 18. Different campsites are also free to place their own laws which will variry. If you gave your honest age when booking it will probably be fine

Comment: Has it come to this?  *Youth hostels* banning *youth*?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/16475/566

Comment: @gerrit well they have to draw the line somewhere.  Would you expect them to accommodate unaccompanied 12-year-olds?  Granted, 18 doesn't seem like the right threshold either.

Comment: @phoog In the 1930s they did, but then they had the level of adult supervision of a kid camp.  Times have changed.  ([Dutch language article](https://www.trouw.nl/home/de-jeugdherbergvader-heet-nu-franchise-ondernemer-~a9eaa4c7/))

Comment: A lot of hostels do let you stay if you're under 18. Go to the city on Hostelz.com, then click the "Suitable For" drop down menu and choose  "Underage without Guardian". [Disclaimer: I helped create Hostelz.com.]

Comment: @traveld +1 please add your comment as an answer, disclaimer and all, and I'll upvote it. OP's question is not uncommon here and your input is very useful; thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Campsites if you're under 18:** It's difficult to find information on campgrounds that allow you to stay if you're under 18.  As far as I know, there isn't a website that specifically lets you search for hostels that allow minors. But one starting point you can try is https://www.pitchup.com by doing a search and then choosing to filter by "student groups welcome".  That's not quite the same thing, but it's a good way to narrow down your list to the ones that are much more likely to be ok with you staying there.  But you'll still need to contact the campground first to be sure.

**Hostels if you're under 18:** Since you mentioned that you were first thinking about hostels, a lot of hostels do let you stay if you're under 18. To see a list of hostels that let you stay if you're under 18, you can go to https://www.hostelz.com, search for the city you want, then click the "Suitable For" drop down menu and choose "Underage without Guardian". As far as I know, this is the only website that has a search filter to find hostels that allow minors.

[Disclaimer: I helped create Hostelz.com.]